# Why can I bind a form to $index, but not interpolate names?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create `ng-form`s based on the population of an array. The array has elements N through M, and looks similar to this.

```
[ { name: 'MyForm N'}, { name: 'MyForm N+1' }, ...., { name: 'MyForm M' }]
```

I'm using the `ng-repeat` directive to create this list of forms. I would like to publish this list of forms inside of the scope object `MyForms` - to do this, I encapsulate the repeated forms within another form named accordingly.

```
<div ng-form='MyForms'>
    <div ng-repeat='form in forms'>
        <div ng-form='form.name'>
            <input type='text' name='Foo'>Bar</input>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Obviously, this example fails, because `ng-form` expects a string, and takes `form.name` a little more literally than I would like, publishing each form in turn to `form.name` (overwriting the previous form).

My question is - why does this occur with `form.name`, however I can use `$index` (from `ng-repeat`) in the exact same place and I get my desired result (albeit without `MyForms` being denoted with `form.name`)? I understand that `ng-form` expects a string, and not an expression, but isn't `$index` part of an expression?

Comment: Have you tried `<div ng-form='{{form.name}}'>`?

Comment: Yes. http://plnkr.co/edit/3zqlBCQ7odJTIGDjQcQC?p=preview

Comment: I can't understand why you say `$index` is working fine. Can you give an example (plunker)?

Comment: I was using `ref{{$index}}` in place of `{{form.name}}`. Sorry, I can't provide a plunkr, as I'm currently not on that branch and am working on changes that I don't wanna stash and lose my train of thought. This worked fine up until I needed to use `ng-class`, which doesn't use interpolation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since 1.3.0-rc.3 it is possible to assign an expression as the attribute name value of a form or input element.

So this should work:

```
<div ng-form="MyForms">
    <div ng-repeat="form in forms">
        <div ng-form="{{form.name}}">
            <input type="text" name="Foo">Bar</input>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the commit that added the support: [link](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/729c238e19ab27deff01448d79342ea53721bfed)

Comment: Ah. I was using 1.3.0-rc.1. Thank you